# Let $b<c$ and $A\subset(b,c)$ prove that $A$ is Lebesgue measurable if and only if $m^*(A)+m^*((b,c)\setminus A)= c-b $.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $b<c$  and $A\subset(b,c)$ prove that $A$ is Lebesgue measurable if and only if $m^*(A)+m^*((b,c)\cap A^c)= c-b $.

here $m^*$ is the outer measure. What I know here is that if the set $A$ is Lebesgue measurable, then there exists a Borel set $B\subset A$ such that $m^*(A/B)=0$

How do I use this fact to show the previous result. Hint would be nice. Thank you